# Как прочитатать данные cookie в Node

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

Сохраняю Id юзера на PHP в куки. Как я могу прочитать эту куки из Node используя модуль *express*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример работы с cookie

```
var express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('home/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)
  console.log(req.cookies.some_value)
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Также cookie можно проверить запустив сервер, используя консоль на клиентском JS

```
document.cookie
```

Стандартная функция, которая используется для поиска cookie

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
```

Источники для работы с cookie:

[github](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser)

[Express](http://expressjs.com/ru/api.html)

Comment: попробовал вывести в консоль console.log('User ID is '+req.signedCookies.user); вышла ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Comment: @vkt `cookie-parser` подключили?

Comment: сейчас домой приеду, исправлю

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, нет cookie-parser не ставил,щас напишу хостеру чтоб установили потому что у меня прав админа нет